# Multiplication in Ruby

Tags: ruby, user-input, multiplication

I am trying to multiple a variable (input from the user) and `4`.  For some reason, this simple task can not be completed by me.

Here is the code:

```
print "Enter an Integer between 1 and 12: "
x = gets
puts x * 4
```

Instead of multiplying `x` and `4`, it will print `x` a total of four times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `x` is a string, and the `*` method on strings is repetition.  You need  to convert it to a number using the `#to_i` method first.

```
x = gets.to_i
puts x * 4
```

Should do what you want.

Comment: That seemed to work!  Thank you so much for the help!   Sorry for the noob question :P